# Уникальное значение из функции для каждой кнопки в цикле. python. tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Помогите сообразить, пожалуйста. Я создаю фрейм, кладу в него лейбл и кнопку и пакую несколько таких фреймов через цикл. Так же, есть функция, которая принимает на вход строку. Как сделать так, что бы каждая кнопка, созданная через цикл, могла передать в функцию текст из лейбла на том же фрейме, на котором находится сама кнопка. Сколько не пытался выдумывать различные конструкции, результат всегда один - любая кнопка выводит только последний запакованный лейбл.
Вот пример кода:

```
root = tk.Tk()

def get_label_text(text):
    print(text)

for i in range(5):
    frame = tk.Frame(root)
    label = tk.Label(frame, text=f'text {i}')
    button = tk.Button(frame, text=f'button {i}', command=lambda: get_label_text(label.cget('text')))

    frame.pack()
    label.pack(side='left')
    button.pack(side='left')

root.mainloop()
```